# Vue multiselect not showing data on edit form laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have used vue multiselect in my form in my laravel 
Problem is vue is not showing the data of multiselect in the edit form but it is getting the proper data .

My form

```
<multiselect v-model="selected" :options="options" :loading="isLoading" :internal-search="false" :multiple="true" :close-on-select="false" :hide-selected="true" name="books[]" @search-change="getData" label="name" track-by="id"></multiselect>
```

My Vue file

```
import AppForm from '../app-components/Form/AppForm';

Vue.component('coupon-form', {
    mixins: [AppForm],
    data: function() {
        return {
            form: {
                name:  '' ,
                description:  '' ,
                valid_from:  '' ,
                valid_till:  '' ,
                discount:  '' ,
                enabled:  false,
                books: [],
            },
            isLoading: false,
            options: [],
            selected: [],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getData(query){
            this.isLoading = true;
            axios.post('/admin/books/find/'+query)
            .then((response) => {
                this.options = response.data;
                this.isLoading = false;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.isLoading = false;
            });
        },
    },
    watch: {
        selected (newValues) {
             this.form.books = newValues.map(obj => obj.id);
        }

    }
});
```

and In my controller

```
 $rules = json_decode($coupon->rules);
        $coupon['thrash_limit'] = $rules->orders_limit ?? '';
        $coupon['thrash_amount'] = $rules->amount ?? '';
        $coupon['thrash_discount'] = $rules->percent ?? '';
        $coupon['books'] = $rules->books ?? '';
        $coupon['free_delivery'] = $rules->free_delivery ?? false;
        return view('admin.coupons.edit', [
            'coupon' => $coupon,
        ]);
```

Note: Rules is a json type data which takes the multiselect values called books
In my devTool I checked it is getting the data like this

[image]

Anyone can tell how to do that

Comment: In your `Vue` file what is the `newValues`?

Comment: have you installed `vue` [developer extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en)

Comment: newValues takes the object of selected values

Comment: @Md.Amirozzaman yes I have vue devTool

Comment: is devTool referencing any error?if so,please include it in your question.

Comment: No any error . I need to push the object values of books to selected I think